# Rename file using Python, based from an input file

Tags: python

I want to try renaming files with the following file names:

I have a long list within a file with the following columns. This is an input file which has MD5sums in the first column and new names in the the second column:

```
1c59eb1e8d29fecc54d3a0623e6f4c8d Worm:Win32/Allaple.A
1c569fda69ad93670bf611ff2d16baa6 W32.Rahack.W
1c6481ebf5c2e86555b88862c0df597b Worm:Win32/Allaple.A
1c0aa69cbe2b2ed08dc6e73fb2bf1d34 Virus:Win32/Virut.AC
1c6fdcabb61b5b1d6e53280ae934eaa6 Worm:Win32/Allaple.A
1c781a8051fcfac49b62cdfba1d7510f Worm:Win32/Allaple.A
```

Let say;

from an original filename with MD5SUM, I want to change from

```
Worm.Allaple.A_1c781a8051fcfac49b62cdfba1d7510f.exe.csv
```

to

```
Worm:Win32/Allaple.A_1c781a8051fcfac49b62cdfba1d7510f.exe.csv
```

How to do this on Python (I tried with bash too.. but my skill is limited so try to look in another option)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried on Bash. something like this for i  in `cat microsoft-naming.csv |awk {'print $2'}`; do mv $i `cat microsoft-naming.csv|awk {'print $1'}` -v ;done .. but I couldn't grab the logic

Comment: If you want a bash solution, the question should be tagged bash... If you want a python solution, please try it in python. Hint: You might take a look at the shutil module

Answer (score 1):

solved with bash with some helps

```
sed -n 's/.*_\(.*\)\.exe\.csv/\1 \0/p' old-name.txt  | sort > n1.txt

sort input-name-file.csv > temp.txt

join -j1 temp.txt n1.txt > j1.txt

tr '/' ':' < j1.txt | awk '{printf "mv %s %s_%s.exe.csv\n",$3,$2,$1}'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can rename files with python using shutil

```
import shutil

# make sure you are passing the correct directory
shutil.move(old_file_name, new_file_name)
```

Comment: thanks. I will try with Python too. since I need have some "error checking" to mistakenly renaming a file with wrong name..

Comment: Maybe.. You misunderstood the question. He/She probably want to know how to find a specific pattern and replace it properly.